# Check if associative multi-dimensional arrays are equal regardless of order of keys in either level

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, comparison, associative-array

The two arrays are considered equal since they have the same 1st dimension indexes (Electric, Gas, Water) the same 2nd dimension indexes (Gym, Library), and the same values for each intersect.  The second level values will always be scalar (not arrays or objects).  Order doesn't matter.

How can PHP verify that they are equal based on the above definition of equality?

```
$array1 = [
    'Electric' => ['Gym' => 24, 'Library' => 25],
    'Gas' => ['Gym' => 13, 'Library' => null],
    'Water' => ['Gym' => null, 'Library' => null]
];

$array2 = [
    'Gas' => ['Library' => null, 'Gym' => 13],
    'Electric' => ['Gym' => 24, 'Library' => 25],
    'Water' => ['Library' => null, 'Gym' => null]
];
```

My attempt is as follows...

```
if (count($arr1) != count($arr2) || array_diff($arr1, $arr2) !== array_diff($arr2, $arr1)) {
    $error = 'Values do not match.';
}
```

Comment: Not homework, and I can post my attempts if you like.  There were a couple of similar questions, but none with real answers.  EDIT.  Added my attempt to the original question.

Comment: https://3v4l.org/s3Quu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a recursive comparison function

```
function CompareRecursive($array1, $array2, &$mismatches) {
    foreach ($array1 as $key => $value) {
        if (!isset($array2[$key])) { 
            $mismatches[$key] = [ $value ];
            continue;
        } 

        $value2 = $array2[$key];  
        if (!is_array($value) || !is_array($value2)) {                
            if ($value != $value2) {
                $mismatches[$key] = [
                    $value, $value2
                ];
            }
        } else {
            $mismatches_internal = [];
            CompareRecursive($value, $value2, $mismatches_internal);
            if (!empty($mismatches_internal)) {
                $mismatches[$key] = $mismatches_internal;
            }
        } 
    }
    return empty($mismatches);
}
```

As an added bonus this keeps track of mismatched entries too, there's a drawback when using this method that it won't work if `$array2` has extra elements that `$array1` doesn't but you can resolve this by doing:

```
$isEqual = CompareRecursive($array1,$array2) && CompareRecursive($array2,$array1);
```

Comment: While I only need two levels, I like your general use of a recursive function.  Using `uniqid()`, however, seems a little odd.

Answer (score 0):

Simple code is:

```
$arr2;
$arr1;

$eq = true;
if (count($arr1) == count($arr2)) {
    foreach ($arr1 as $k => $v) {
        if (empty($arr2[$k]) || $arr2[$k]['Gym'] != $v['Gym'] || $arr2[$k]['Library'] != $v['Library']) {
            $eq = false;
            break;
        }
    }
} else {
    $eq = false;
}

var_dump($eq);
```

**Update:**
Without fixed keys inner `foreach` becomes:

```
foreach ($arr1 as $k => $v) {
    if (empty($arr2[$k]) || array_diff_assoc($arr2[$k], $v)) {
        $eq = false;
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe I should have said so, but the index names such as `Gym` or `Gas` cannot be hardcoded as they can be any string.

Answer (score 0):

```
function arrayTwoLevelEquivalence(array $a, array $b) {
    if (count($a) !== count($b)) {
        return false;
    }
    foreach ($a as $k => $a2) {
        if (!isset($b[$k])) {
            return false;
        }
        $b2 = $b[$k];
        if (count($a2) !== count($b2)) {
            return false;
        }
        foreach ($a2 as $k2 => $v) {
            if (!array_key_exists($k2, $b2) || $b2[$k2] !== $v) {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

I decline to use `array_diff_assoc()` because I do not support unnecessary transient allocation of heap memory for the sake of convenience.

Comment: Definitely don't want unnecessary transient allocation of heap memory!  Just curious, what does that mean?

Comment: @user1032531: lol.  it means that `array_diff_assoc()` calculates the actual array diff as its result, meaning that result array has to be allocated in memory.  Somewhere buried in the guts of PHP, that's going to be a `malloc()` on a [heap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap_(data_structure)).  Scripting languages like PHP encourage you to think as if memory allocation were a free operation, but it's very much not (cf. "malloc churn", "heap fragmentation"), and we don't actually *care* about the array diff, just the yes/no question of equivalence.

Answer (score 0):

```
$array1 = array("a" => "green", 'b'=>"red", 'c'=>"blue");
$array2 = array('b'=>"red", 'c'=>"blue", "a" => "green");
echo empty(array_diff_assoc($array1, $array2));
```

check it, hope it will fulfill your requirements. It will check if both associative array are same, whether it has same order or not.

**Check it for your multidimensional array** -

```
function array_diff_assoc_recursive($array1, $array2)
{
foreach($array1 as $key => $value)
{
    if(is_array($value))
    {
        if(!isset($array2[$key]))
        {
            $difference[$key] = $value;
        }
        elseif(!is_array($array2[$key]))
        {
            $difference[$key] = $value;
        }
        else
        {
            $new_diff = array_diff_assoc_recursive($value,   $array2[$key]);
            if($new_diff != FALSE)
            {
                $difference[$key] = $new_diff;
            }
        }
    }
    elseif(!isset($array2[$key]) || $array2[$key] != $value)
    {
        $difference[$key] = $value;
    }
}
return !isset($difference) ? 0 : $difference;
}
```

I have found it from [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/780780/PHP-Finding-differences-in-two-multidimensional-ar)

Comment: If this works, it is way too easy!  Let me test and get back to you.  Thanks

Comment: Unfortunately, multi-dimensional arrays do not appear to be supported.

Comment: Have you tested it using array_diff?

Comment: Yes, but get the same error about multi-dimensional arrays and changing of variable types.

Answer (score 0):

If all you need to know is they match or not - without any further details:

```
function ksortRecursive(&$array)
{
    if (is_array($array)) {
        ksort($array);
        foreach ($array as &$arr) {
            ksortRecursive($arr);
        }
    }
}

ksortRecursive($arr1);
ksortRecursive($arr2);

if (serialize($arr1) == serialize($arr2)) {
    echo "match!";
}
```